# Event Binding - jQuery vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the differences between using

```
$("#element").click(function() { alert("test"); });
```

and

```
<div id="element" onclick="alert('test');"></div>
```

Is there any difference in performance, functionality or anything else? Should I be using the *jQuery way*, when I can simply use an `onclick` attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Why Inline JavaScript Code Is Such A Bad Thing](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/)

and

[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter1.html)

It's also always better to use a framework for binding javascript events, since there are cross-browser things you need to take care of yourself if you don't (attachEvent..).

Comment: A bit dogmatic to say "it's always better to use a framework for binding JavaScript events" - if you're using a general purpose library such as jQuery just for that then you're forcing your users to download a load of things they don't need. Also, binding events is simply not that hard. And I wouldn't say it's always better to use the "unobtrusive" way either.

Comment: See also [Behavioral Separation][1] article on ala.

  [1]: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation/

Answer (score 18):

jQuery's `click` (as well as most of the other libraries' event abstractions) uses standard [DOM L2 `addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) or MSHTML proprietary (and later copied by some other browsers, like Opera) [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx), when `addEventListener` is not available.

If neither `addEventListener`, not `attachEvent` are present (as is the case with some of the ancient browsers), jQuery does nothing (as of 1.4a2).

`onclick="..."` from your second example is what's called an [intrinsic event attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3), and is defined in HTML 4.01. The value of such event attribute becomes a function body of an event handler. When event occurs, this handler function is invoked with `event` as a first argument; function scope chain is also [usually augmented](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/names/event_handler.html) to include some of the element's ancestors and element itself.

The benefits of intrinsic event attribute is **wider browser support** and arguably **better performance**. I remember seeing tests of event attributes resulting in a much lesser memory consumption, comparing to those initialized via `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`. I can't find those tests at the moment.

By avoiding `attachEvent`, you also avoid memory leaks in IE, naturally. Most of the popular Javascript libraries actually create circular references in their event abstractions, and are then forced to perform a clean up on page unload in IE. Obviously, these problems disappear when you avoid event abstractions that rely on `attachEvent`.

The downsides of event attributes, however, is **lack of reusability**, **breaking separation of concerns** and **markup pollution** (affecting both — size of document, and its maintainability). Remember that logic from event attribute is constantly transferred to a client, instead of being part of external script that's downloaded once and cached. There is also a chance of being tripped on augmented scope.

I would recommend to **avoid event attributes**, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: You can also combine these practices, i.e. use document.getElementById("theElement").onclick=theFunction; in a window.onload function in a separate JavaScript file. Then you don't have to check whether addEventListener or attachEvent is supported and your JavaScript is binded in an unobtrusive way. Or is this a really bad practice for some reason?